# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null error message

Tags: javascript, xml

I've been trying to pass through JS variables via the onChange event but keep receiving the

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

under Google Chrome. Here is my code below:

```
    artistID = album_select.substring(0, album_select.indexOf('/'));
    albumID = album_select.substring(album_select.indexOf('/')+1, album_select.length);     
    var count = 0;
    var tracklist = '';
    for(track in albumlist[albumID][2]){
        count++;
        tracklist+="<option id='"+album+"'>"+track+"</option>";             
        } 
    hstr+="<form><select size='"+count+"' onChange='parent.loadSong(this.value, document.getElementById(\"album_select\").firstChild.nodeValue, document.getElementById(\"artistID\").firstChild.nodeValue)' style='font-size:2em;'>";
    hstr+=tracklist;
    hstr+="</form></select>";
```

Comment: can u show the html for album_select and artistID please?

Answer (score 1):

This part of the string:

```
document.getElementById(\"artistID\")
```

Is looking for an ID of `"artistID"`.

I assume you meant to concatenate the variable.

```
"...document.getElementById('" + artistID + "')..."
```

Sounds like this one needs it too:

```
"...document.getElementById('" + album_select + "')..."
```

Comment: So `hstr+="<form><select size='"+count+"' onChange='parent.loadSong(this.value, document.getElementById(\"album_select\").firstChild.nodeValue, document.getElementById(\"artistID\").firstChild.nodeValue)' style='font-size:2em;'>";` would be `hstr+="<form><select size='"+count+"' onChange='parent.loadSong(this.value, document.getElementById('" + album_select"').firstChild.nodeValue, document.getElementById('" + artistID "').firstChild.nodeValue)' style='font-size:2em;'>";`

Comment: @methuselah: I misread your code in the comment. I don't know, but it would seem like that's what you'd want, except for the `album_select` part seems messed up.

Comment: So the `tracks()` function is getting an argument passed, which is referenced by `album_select`. Do you anticipate there being an element on the page that has an ID of that exact same value?

Comment: @methuselah: Then in that case  you need to concatenate the value into the string. The code in your comment above doesn't quite do it. I'll update my answer to change that line of code.